# How to generate a total sum with a Django QuerySet and display in a template?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-queryset

I'm using `annotate` with my Django queryset to count a number of records. I am using it with `filter` and understand the order makes a difference.

My query is: `numcontestants = Contestant.objects.filter(assigned_team__id=urlid).annotate(num_contestants=Count('id'))`

When I pass numcontestants to my template and display it with `{{ numcontestants }}` I see a queryset containing each of the records I want to view. When I try with:

`{{ numcontestants.num_contestants }}` I get nothing.

I don't want to have to iterate over numcontestants to get a count, my understanding was that `num_contestants` should be a single integer number. Even so, iterating over doesn't give the result I am after, for example using:

`{% for x in numcontestants %} {{x.num_contestants}} {% endfor %}`

outputs `1 1 1` when I am trying to get something that will output `3`.

What is the right way to generate and access a sum count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

annotate return a number for each record, you can get num_contestants for the first record:

```
{{ numcontestants.0.num_contestants }}
```

if you want to get a number of queryset results can use `.count()` in your quesyset

```
numcontestants = Contestant.objects.filter(assigned_team__id=urlid).count()
```

Comment: Ahh so simple, thank you. Everything I was reading on how to count records seemed to indicate count had to be used with annotate, I didn't realize I could use count directly on the queryset. Feel foolish for having missed something so obvious now.